# Boolean Simplification - Why does (A + NOT(B.C)).(B + NOT(B.C)).(C + NOT(B.C)) = A + NOT B.C

Tags: boolean, simplification, boolean-algebra

This is the answer to the equation, but I do not understand why. Please help!

Comment: Try expanding `B + NOT(B*C)`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about boolean algebra, not programming.

Comment: But I tagged boolean algebra into the question so obviously it's about that?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply the **Laws of Boolean Algebra** one by one, the solution is a direct result:

1. *de Morgan´s Theorem*: The complement of two terms joined together by `OR` is the same as the complements of two terms joined by `AND`, and vice versa (i.e. `NOT(A + B) = NOT(A) * NOT(B)` and `NOT(A * B) = NOT(A) + NOT(B)`).
2. *Commutative Law*: The order of joining two separate terms with `AND` or `OR` is not important.
3. *Complement Law*: A term joined with its complement with `AND` equals `0` respectively with `OR` equals `1` (i.e. `A * NOT(A) = 0` and `A + NOT(A) = 1`).
4. *Annulment Law*: A term joined with `AND` with `0` equals `0` and joined with `OR` with a `1` equals `1` (i.e. `A * 0 = 0` and `A + 1 = 1`).
5. *Identity Law*: A term joined with `1` by `AND` or with `0` by `OR` is equal to itself (i.e. `A * 1 = A` and `A + 0 = A`).

(there are more, but you don't need them here)

Applied to your term:

```
              (A + NOT(B*C))        * (B + NOT(B*C))        * (C + NOT(B*C)) 
[with 1.]   = (A + NOT(B) + NOT(C)) * (B + NOT(B) + NOT(C)) * (C + NOT(B) + NOT(C))
[with 2.]   = (A + NOT(B) + NOT(C)) * (B + NOT(B) + NOT(C)) * (C + NOT(C) + NOT(B))
[with 3.]   = (A + NOT(B) + NOT(C)) * (1          + NOT(C)) * (1          + NOT(B))      
[with 4.]   = (A + NOT(B) + NOT(C)) *  1                    *  1      
[with 5.]   = (A + NOT(B) + NOT(C))  
[with 1.]   = (A + NOT(B*C))
```